# Tengo dificultades con ckeditor con django en producción utilizo servidor Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, ckeditor

Este es el error con las migraciones en el servidor

```
(ImperiaDigital) root@imperiadigitalhost:/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigit
al# python3 manage.py makemigrations tips
Migrations for 'tips':
  tips/migrations/0003_auto_20201021_0258.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 182, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 208, in write_migration_files
    self.stdout.write('    - %s' % operation.describe())
  File "/home/imperiadigital/homes/ImperiaDigital/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 147, in write
    self._out.write(style_func(msg))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from equipos.models import Equipo
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

objects = models.Manager ()

class Tip(models.Model):
    equipo = models.ForeignKey(Equipo, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    título = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categoría = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descripción = RichTextField(blank=True)
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, blank=True)
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)   
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.título
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'equipos.apps.EquiposConfig',
    'tips.apps.TipsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
]

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['RemoveFormat', 'Source']
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente tienes un caracter no-ascii en un script. Python espera por defecto que los scripts sean ascii de 7 bits. Tendrías que indicar que el encoding del scripts es UTF-8 (o alguna otra cosa, lo que corresponda), por ejemplo, con una línea como esta:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-encodings.html

Answer (score 0):

No sé porque genera un problema al momento de editar un proyecto django cuando está en producción en el servidor Ubuntu 18.04 cuando cambias la configuración de settings.py cuando está en español como se puede ver acontinuación

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Para que funcione como debe de ser se tiene que mantener en:

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```